# I can't set Session Items in laravel inertia

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using Laravel with inertia, but I am not able to set session items in laravel.
here is my laravel code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;    
public function index()
        {
            Session::put('message', 'showCatergories');
            $categories = Category::all();
            return Inertia::render('Admin/Categories', ['categories' => $categories]);
        }
```

nothing appears in  application -> storage-> sessoin storage
my route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'web'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/categories', CategoriesController::class);
});
```

How to tackle this issue?

Comment: If you add `dd(session()->all());` after you put your data in the session, then you will see that the session data is most likely present. It sounds like you're looking to find the session on the actual disk? By default, session are stored here: `storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: it actually works... thank you so much for that reason to get session messages in inertiaJs to use it in SPA we need to add flash in theHandleInertiaRequest class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'flash' => [
                'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
            ],
        ]);
    }
} please linus can you add your answer to determine it as the answer of the question

Comment: There you go, I added an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with session items and flash messages in Inertia.js is done by appending it to the shared method in the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware.

```php
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'flash' => [
                'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here we get the message item on the session and append it as a `flash` prop on the request.

Then we can use it in our frontend of choice. Here is a React.js example:

```js
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const { flash } = usePage().props

  return (
    <main>
      <header></header>
      <content>
        {flash.message && (
          <div class="alert">{flash.message}</div>
        )}
        {children}
      </content>
      <footer></footer>
    </main>
  )
}
```

You can read more about flash messages in the [documentation](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages).